# Is it possible to use all possible types from reflection as generic type?

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to automatically create savedStateHandle for some classes.

```
fun <T> KProperty1<T, *>.argFrom(handle: SavedStateHandle) = 
    when (this.returnType.javaType) {
        String::class.java -> handle.get<String>(this.name)
        Int::class.java -> handle.get<Int>(this.name)
        Uri::class.java -> handle.get<Uri>(this.name)
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Type not implemented yet")
    }
```

As you see IF the type is for instance `String` then I want the return type of get function to be `String` and when doing it this way I have to define every single case manually.

It would be nice if I could just do something like this.

```
fun <T> KProperty1<T, *>.argFrom(handle: SavedStateHandle) =
    handle.get<this.returnType.javaType>(this.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type parameter for the return type of the property. Then you can use that type parameter to specify the desired return type of `get`:

```
fun <T, V> KProperty1<T, V>.argFrom(handle: SavedStateHandle) =
    handle.get<V>(this.name)
```

Comment: Thank you - actually I did something similar - I added a `V` parameter where the `*` was and then used that in the `get` method on `handle`

Comment: You are completely right, @mama, that's exactly how it should be. I rewrote the answer based on your comment.